# R: How to create matrix in a loop using cast-function?

Tags: r, matrix, casting

I try to make a yearly country import matrix out of a yearly `list` using the `cast` function in the `reshape-package`. As I try this for a single year everything works fine. See code (test-dataset below!) :

`OCTC2011 <- cast(OC ~ TC, data =Import_Year[["2011"]], value = "Value")`

The result is a matrix containing the import-values of the year 2011 from the origin-country (OC) (rows) to the target-country (TC) (columns).

However, as I use a large dataset consisting of different products for different years, I want to put this procedure in a loop. I tried following:

```
library(reshape)
OCTC <- 0
for(i in 1:length(unique(Import_Year))) 
{
  OCTC[i] <- cast(OC ~ TC, data =Import_Year[[i]], value = "Value")
}
```

Which delivers the warning: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`, probably due to a wrong indexing as I'am hardly familiar with loops.

Here I produced a simple dataset for my problem:

```
OC <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D")
TC <- c("Z", "Z", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "W", "W")
Value <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Year <- c(2010,2011)
df_import <- data.frame(OC,TC,Value, Year)
Import_Year <- split(df_import, df_import$Year)
```

I appreciate every comment on this. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need the `rehape2` package here instead of `reshape`, then `dcast` instead of `cast` and finally `value.var` instead of `value`.

Comment: reshape2 didn't work, but thanks for the idea

Comment: So what didn't work exactly? It seems like the exact same thing worked in the answer below.

Comment: after trying your idea, I get the 2nd answer and using list() instead of 0 let it work, even as you mentioned with the reshape2-package. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidArenburg comments you should probably use the `dcast` function from the `reshape2` package using the `value.var` argument.

Apart from that the loop should be something like this in order to work:

```
library(reshape2)
OCTC <- list()
for(i in 1:length(unique(Import_Year))) 
{
  OCTC[[length(OCTC)+1]] <- dcast(OC ~ TC, data =Import_Year[[i]], value.var = "Value")
}
```

So, you initiate a list using `list()` (and not a variable with the value of zero) and then you add each dcast as an element to that list.

Output:

```
> OCTC
[[1]]
  OC  W  X  Y  Z
1  A NA NA NA  1
2  B NA NA  3 NA
3  C NA  5 NA NA
4  D  7 NA NA NA

[[2]]
  OC  W  X  Y  Z
1  A NA NA NA  2
2  B NA NA  4 NA
3  C NA  6 NA NA
4  D  8 NA NA NA
```

Comment: @N.Varela Cool! Glad I could help :)