# R: How to match/join 2 matrices of different dimensions (nrow/ncol) in a LOOP?

Tags: r, matrix

In addition to my earlier question [R: How to match/join 2 matrices of different dimensions (nrow/ncol)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050787/r-how-to-match-join-2-matrices-of-different-dimensions-nrow-ncol) I need a loop as I have a list of more than 1000 matrices. I decide to use the code (from the answers)

```
full_matrix[rownames(full_matrix) %in% rownames(small_matrix), 
            colnames(full_matrix) %in% colnames(small_matrix)] <- small_matrix
```

which worked fine in my case for a single matrix match. However, I have problems implementing this code into a loop for the `list` of `matrices` "small_matrix". Here my code:

```
full_matrix <- list()
for(i in 1:length(small_matrix)) 
{
  full_matrix[i][rownames(full_matrix[i]) %in% rownames(small_matrix[i]), 
                 colnames(full_matrix[i]) %in% colnames(small_matrix[i])] <- small_matrix[i]
}
```

I get the error: `incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`, which is probably due to a wrong indexing in my basic knowledge of loops. I appreciate any help. Thanks

**NEW EDIT according to answer of @Jim M.:**
Your answer works fine for this example but the small_matrix(ces) should be created as well in a loop like in this former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760067/r-how-to-create-matrix-in-a-loop-using-cast-function). Here you find the code example:

```
library(abind)

a = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
full_matrix = array(dim=c(6,6,2))
dimnames(full_matrix) <- list(levels(as.factor(a)), levels(as.factor(a)), 
                              c("mat1","mat2"))
```

as @Jim M. advises. And here the new code:

```
##### new part for small matrix
df_import <- data.frame(OC = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"),
                        TC = c("Z", "Z", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "W", "W"),
                        Value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                        Year = c(2010,2011))
Import_Year <- split(df_import, df_import$Year)

library(reshape2)
small_matrix <- list()
for(i in 1:length(unique(Import_Year))) 
{
  small_matrix[[length(small_matrix)+1]] <- dcast(OC ~ TC, data =Import_Year[[i]], value.var = "Value")
}
small_matrix
##### end new part
```

and than further the for-loop of @Jim. M:

```
for(i in seq_along(small_matrix_list)){
  afill(full_matrix[, , i], local= TRUE ) <- small_matrix[[i]]   
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in `afill<-.default`(`*tmp*`, local = TRUE, value = list(OC = 1:4,  : 
  'x' must have names on dimensions corresponding to those in 'value'
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is your full matrix the same for each of the smaller matrices, and do you require a list as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your full "matrix" as a 3-dimensional array rather than a list, and then fill in this array with a list of smaller matrices by looping through the corresponding index of the 3d dimension of the array.

```
library(abind)

a = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
full_matrix = array(dim=c(6,6,2))
dimnames(full_matrix) <- list(levels(as.factor(a)), levels(as.factor(a)), 
    c("mat1","mat2"))

small_matrix_1 = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6), nrow=3, ncol=3)
dimnames(small_matrix_1) <- list(c("B","C","E"), c("A","B","F"))

small_matrix_2 = matrix(c(20, 40, 30, 10, 50, 70, 30, 10, 60), nrow=3, ncol=3)
dimnames(small_matrix_2) <- list(c("B","C","E"), c("A","B","F"))

small_matrix_list <- list(small_matrix_1, small_matrix_2)

for(i in seq_along(small_matrix_list)){
    afill(full_matrix[, , i], local= TRUE ) <- small_matrix_list[[i]]   
}
```

giving 
    full_matrix 
with the 3rd index corresponding to each of the small matrices.

```
, , mat1

   A  B  C  D  E  F
A NA NA NA NA NA NA
B  2  1 NA NA NA  3
C  4  5 NA NA NA  1
D NA NA NA NA NA NA
E  3  7 NA NA NA  6
F NA NA NA NA NA NA

    , , mat2

   A  B  C  D  E  F
A NA NA NA NA NA NA
B 20 10 NA NA NA 30
C 40 50 NA NA NA 10
D NA NA NA NA NA NA
E 30 70 NA NA NA 60
F NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

**Edit:** Instead of creating data.frames with `dcast` as in your previous question, I would cast the data as arrays (`acast`) so that they can inserted into the larger array.

```
library(reshape2) 
small_matrix <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2) # Pre-allocate space in the list

for (i in seq(Import_Year)){
  small_matrix[[i]] <- acast(OC ~ TC, data = Import_Year[[i]], value.var = "Value")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, which worked fine for this example, but I still have a problem in my real data, see edit. Idea? Thanks

Comment: @N.Varela: I've edited my response to your question to address how arrays can be cast within a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit. `acast` works fine

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems:

- Use `[[` to select an element of a list, e.g., `small_matrix[[i]]`.
- `full_matrix` is initialized to an empty list.  Hence `full_matrix[i]` evaluates to `list(NULL)`
- Your initial code assumes that all row and col names of `small_matrix` occur in `full_matrix`.  If they do, you can simplify the assignment as below(*).  (If that's not guaranteed, you'll need to subset both sides by the intersection of the names.)
- Make sure `full_matrix` gets initialized properly.  You might have a list of matrices too, or one common full matrix in which you replace different sub-blocks.

(*)

```
full_matrix[rownames(small_matrix), colnames(small_matrix)] <- small_matrix
```